# While loop with JOptionPane returning StringIndexOutOfBounds Exceptions

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, indexoutofboundsexception, charat

In my code I have a while loop with 3 IF tests nested in between that have flags triggered by ELSE:

[test1] checks whether the input value has a length of exactly 1 [Prevents users from inputting nothing]

[test2] checks whether the input value at index 0 is a digit [I need a number as an input, but I'm using JSWING]

[test3] checks whether the input value length is greater than 1 [2 Digits (10,11,12,...)

```
 num1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please input Guess #" + (counter+1), "0"); 
                 while(exit == false || test1 == false || test2 == false || test3 == false) {
                     if(num1.length() < 1) {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input required");
                         num1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please input Guess #" + (counter+1), "0");
                     }
                     else {
                         test1 = true;
                     }
                     if(Character.isDigit(num1.charAt(0)) == false) {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input has to be a number between 0 - 9.");
                         num1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please input Guess #" + (counter+1), "0");
                     }
                     else {
                         test2 = true;
                     }
                     if(num1.length() > 1) {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input has to be a number between 0 - 9.");
                         num1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please input Guess #" + (counter+1), "0");
                     }
                     else {
                         test3 = true;
                     }
                     if(test1 == true && test2 == true && test3 == true) {
                         exit = true;
                     }
```

The problem I'm having is somewhere between the first and second test. When I try inputting nothing as a value ["" / or just having an empty box and pressing enter], it detects the error of having nothing and displays "Input required" once, but once it loops, it outputs a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for the second trial
It works in every other case I've tried (no input -> correct, no-input -> incorrect...) Only sequential no-input cases crash the program.

The error is said to be in this line, but I don't understand where, or how.

```
if(Character.isDigit(num1.charAt(0)) == false)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)
at oof.Lottery_Swing_FIX.main(Lottery_Swing_FIX.java:56)
```

Fixed Logic

```
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter 3 one-digit positive numbers for your 3 guesses");
             for(int counter = 0; counter < LIMIT; counter++) {
                 test = false; 

                 while(exit == false || test == false) {
                     num1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please input Guess #" + (counter+1), ""); 
                     if(num1.length() < 1 || Character.isDigit(num1.charAt(0)) == false || num1.length() > 1) {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Integer between 1-9 required");
                     }
                     else {
                         test = true;
                     }
                     if(test == true) {
                         numberInput = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                         exit = true;
                     }
                     else {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: Well, if you don't enter anything, you ask the use to re-enter something (`num1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please input Guess #" + (counter+1), "0");`. And then immediately after, you have `if(Character.isDigit(num1.charAt(0)) == false) {`. So if you don't enter anything the second time, it fails, since you try to access the first character of an empty string.

Comment: how would I go about fixing this? I understand the issue, but don't really have a fix. Should I set another input for num1?

Comment: Rework your logic. You should ask the value once and only once in the loop. It should look like: `boolean valid = false; while (!valid) { num1 = getValue(); valid = validateAndShowErrorMessageIfInvalid(num1); }`

Comment: I updated my post, and it does work now, but is there any way to add separate messages detailing what was wrong during the input? Like for example if they had an empty input, or if they put all letters. Since now every error just outputs "Integer between 1-9 required"

Comment: Sure. In the method validateAndShowErrorMessageIfInvalid(), use if blocks to check for errors. Every time an error is found, display the appropriate error message, then return false. Do refactor your code as I explain. Putting everything in the same method makes it much harder to reason about it, and doesn't allow using `return` as soon as you found an error.

Comment: `boolean valid = false; while (!valid)`  can be rewritten as `for (boolean valid = false; !valid; )`

Answer (score 0):

Your 'fix' doesn't handle **null** which will be returned by the **JOptionPane.showInputDialog()** if the dialog is closed (<kbd>x</kbd>) or the cancel <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button is selected. You can't play ***null*** against the **String#length()** method as you can with a ***Null String*** (**""**) so, you need to check for this in your code otherwise you can end up with a **NullPointerException**. You can do this in your very first **if** statement as a conditional component:

```
if (num1 == null) {
    // The CANCEL or dialog close button was selected.
}
```

You really don't need those boolean flags in your code. Things are going to happen or they simply will not. You don't really need flags to remind you so close to home (so to speak). If you have the conditions established properly within the **if** statements and utilize **else if** then they're not required. With that being said, you don't need these boolean flags within the condition for the **while** loop either.

The while loop needs to be concerned about one thing...that the prompt is provided valid data. If it isn't then the variable (**num1**) which holds the prompt data is converted to a null string (""). So in reality:

```
String num1 = "";
while (num1.equals("")) { .... }
```

So, for as long as **num1** contains a null string ("") we just keep looping thus re-prompting for proper input.

In your code, you want to provide the User with specific details as to why their input failed. There are several ways to do this however whichever way you choose to do it, make sure it doesn't generate any exceptions (errors) that can ultimately halt your application or change its accurate performance. There is nothing wrong with using **if** and **else if** statements to carry out this particular task in its current use-case. Following your particular theme:

```
int LIMIT = 3, numberInput;
int[] guesses = new int[LIMIT];
String errMsg;
String num1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>You will be prompted three times "
           + "to supply<br>a positive <font color=red><b>single digit</b></font> "
           + "number.</html>", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
for (int counter = 0; counter < LIMIT; counter++) {
    num1 = "";
    while (num1.equals("")) {
        errMsg = "";
        num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input Guess #" + (counter + 1), 
                                           "Guess #" + (counter + 1),JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        // Does num1 contain null?
        if (num1 == null) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "<html>You <font color=blue>canceled</font> your input!<br>"
                    + "Do you want to quit?</html>", "Quit",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            num1 = ""; // Set for re-prompt.
            continue;
        }
        // Is nothing supplied?
        else if (num1.length() < 1) {
            errMsg = "<html><font size=5 color=red><center>Nothing Supplied!"
                     + "</center></font><br>You must provide a single Integer "
                     + "value between<br>0 and 9 (inclusive).</html>";
        }
        // Is too much supplied?
        else if (num1.length() > 1) {
            errMsg = "<html><center><font size=5 color=red>To Much Supplied!</font><br>" +
                     "<font size=5 color=blue>\"" + num1 + "\"</font></center><br>" +
                     "You must provide a single Integer value between<br>0 and 9 "
                     + "(inclusive).</html>";

        }
        // Is the supplied character a number?
        else if (!Character.isDigit(num1.charAt(0))) {
            errMsg = "<html><center><font size=5 color=red>Invalid Digit Supplied!"
                     + "</font><br><font size=5 color=blue>\"" + num1 + "\"</font>"
                     + "</center><br>You must provide a single Integer value "
                     + "between<br>0 and 9 (inclusive).</html>";
        }

        // Does errMsg actually contain a message? If so display it.
        if (!errMsg.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errMsg, "Invalid Input!", 
                                          JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            num1 = ""; // Set for re-prompt.
        }
        else { 
            numberInput = Integer.parseInt(num1);

            // ... do whatever you want to do with numberInput, for example ....
            guesses[counter] = numberInput;
        }
    }
}

// Display User's LIMITED guesses:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<html>The <font color=red><b>").append(LIMIT).
        append("</b></font> Guesses supplied by User are:<br><br>");

for (int i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
    sb.append("Guess #").append((i + 1)).append(":  <font color=blue>").append(guesses[i]).append("</font><br>");
}
sb.append("</html>");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString(), "Guesses Provided", 
                              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

As you can see, providing details to a User about input failures requires a lot more code. All this code can be removed if you decide you want just a simple "Invalid Input!" message. This in essence forces the User to read the supplied prompts with more intensity, for example:

```
int LIMIT = 3;
int numberInput;
int[] guesses = new int[LIMIT];
String num1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>You will be prompted three times "
        + "to supply<br>a positive <font color=red><b>single digit</b></font> "
        + "number.</html>", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
for (int counter = 0; counter < LIMIT; counter++) {
    num1 = "";
    while (num1.equals("")) {
        num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input Guess #" + (counter + 1), 
                                           "Guess #" + (counter + 1),JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        // Does num1 contain null?
        if (num1 == null){
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "<html>You <font color=blue>canceled</font> your input!<br>"
                    + "Do you want to quit?</html>", "Quit",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            num1 = ""; // Set for re-prompt.
        }
        else if (!num1.matches("\\d")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><center><font size=5 color=red>Invalid Input Supplied!</font><br>" +
                    "<font size=5 color=blue>\"" + num1 + "\"</font></center><br>" +
                    "You must provide a single Integer value between<br>0 and 9 "
                    + "(inclusive).</html>", "Invalid Input!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            num1 = "";
        }
        else { 
            numberInput = Integer.parseInt(num1);

            // ... do whatever you want to do with numberInput, for example ....
            guesses[counter] = numberInput;
        }        
    }
}

// Display User's LIMITED guesses:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<html>The <font color=red><b>").append(LIMIT).
        append("</b></font> Guesses supplied by User are:<br><br>");

for (int i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
    sb.append("Guess #").append((i + 1)).append(":  <font color=blue>").append(guesses[i]).append("</font><br>");
}
sb.append("</html>");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString(), "Guesses Provided", 
                                  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Pay special note to the condition for the **else if** statement (`!num1.matches("\\d)`) in the above code. Here the use of the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method is used with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html), the `"\\d"` expression. This expression tells the **matches()** method to see if the string we're matching (in **num1**) is a **single digit** string numerical value (like: "5" for example). So, what the **else if** statement is asking:

**else if** the string contained in **num1** is **NOT** (!) a single digit string numerical value then run the code in my curly braces ({...}). This basically covers all input failures except null (because we're handling that as a **quit** option) and the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method will not accept null.

If you don't want a **quit** option then then you would only need a single **if** statement in your code:

```
if (num1 == null || !num1.matches("\\d")) { ... }
```